# Rails 3 gmaps4rails (clicking on the map)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Im trying to do a click on map that shows some info. Im using google API's

```
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
alert("You clicked the map.");
});
};
```

but this is not working, It doesnt no anything

Comment: @apneadiving never skips such questions :)

Comment: @fl00r: ;) Indeed: I feel like a father's duty regarding my gem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're simply not getting the map object properly: it's stored in the Gmaps4Rails namespace:

```
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
  google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.map, "click", function() {
    alert("You clicked the map.");
  });
};
```

Comment: @Çağdaş: replace `Gmaps4Rails.map` with `Gmaps.map.serviceObject`